# find initialisms from abbreviations in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of acronyms and what I want to do is find their definitions in a text and then put them into a dictionary. I have made a code but is hardcoded and does not produce the wanted result. I want my end result to be something like this.

```
 {'NBA': ' National Basketball Association', 'NCAA': 'National Collegiate Athletic Association'}
```

code:

```
dict = {}
full_form = ' '
s = " NBA  comes from the words National Basketball Association is a men's professional basketball league in North America, composed of 30 teams. On the other hand NCAA stands for The National Collegiate Athletic Association"


acro = ['NBA', 'NCAA']

for char in range(len(acro)):
    for n,word in enumerate (list_str):
        if acro[char][0] == word[0] and word not in acro:
            full_form += word + ' '
            print(full_form)
            if acro[char][1] == list_str[n+1][0] and word not in acro:
                print(list_str[n+1])
                full_form += list_str[n+1] + ' '
                if acro[char][2] == list_str[n+2][0] and word not in acro:
                    full_form += list_str[n+2] + ''
                    d[acro[char]] = full_form
print(d)
out: {'NBA': ' National Basketball Association', 'NCAA': ' National Basketball AssociationNorth National National North National Collegiate Athletic'}
```

Any help on how to achieve my expected result in a pythonic wat would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can apply regular expression there.

Comment: Do you want your code to understand definitions from arbitrary text? If so then it's an ML\DS topic, lookup Named Entity Recognition, but it's not that easy.

Comment: ^ yes i do. You think it can be done only with NLP?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example how you can apply regular expressions:

```
import re

s = " NBA  comes from the words National Basketball Association is a men's professional basketball league in North America, composed of 30 teams. On the other hand NCAA stands for The National Collegiate Athletic Association"
acro = ['NBA', 'NCAA', 'STFU']

patterns = [f'({a}).+?({" ".join(c + "[a-z]+" for c in a)})(?: |$)' for a in acro]
# python 3.8
result = dict(m.groups() for p in patterns if (m := re.search(p, s)))
# lower versions
result = dict(m.groups() for m in (re.search(p, s) for p in patterns) if m)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/2m42bL/1) is an example of regular expression which will be generated for `'NCAA'`:

```
(NCAA).+(N[a-z]+ C[a-z]+ A[a-z]+ A[a-z]+)(?: |$)
```

Comment: thank you. I cannot test it though as I'm now working on 3.8 with this new operator.

Comment: @hipocampus777, I've added option for older python versions.

Comment: Thank you. It works for the case that the abbreviation precedes the full form, not the other way around, if the full form is before the abbreviation.

Comment: @hipocampus777, yes, that's why I said that it's *simple example*. Main idea was to share how to apply regular expressions for solving this task. You should improve regular expression, but main idea won't be changed.